# Invalide ICache in other threads after binary patching on the fly in Linux (using IPI?)

Tags: linux, x86-64, interrupt

I am trying to find a way to program IPI in Linux to see if it could be used to flush instructions caches across multiple cores (x86_64). Just found similar function for Windows at [1]. Is there is a equivalent in Linux for that? Do I need to be kernel mode to issue IPIs? Is there a way to do that from user land?

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683148(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You are looking it on a way too lower abstraction level. Just use the cacheflush() system call - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/cacheflush.2.html

Comment: I am assuming that this is related to CLFLUSH  instruction http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_30.html which I tried for my use case without success. Wouldn't it only cancel the icache line on the executing CPU? (And rely on cache coherence afterwards to propagate changes). I want a synchronous icache flush across multiple cores so that it is guaranteed the binary patch done from one core is immediately visible to other cores as well.

Comment: This is why I wrote you are looking at this at a too low abstraction level - the system call would send an IPI to any CPU that ran/run the specific process to execute whatever is needed to flush the cache

Comment: Cool. I will try this out and see if this works for my use case.

Comment: @chamibuddhika: be careful with binary patching if you don't pause the other threads while you do it.  You can't guarantee that another thread doesn't try to run a half-rewritten version of the code, unless they can't be executing the code you're modifying.